# (UEFI Hyper-V) Arch-Linux GRUB never installs correctly

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub, uefi, hyper-v

I need to get Arch Linux running on a VM for a university assignment.

I've been trying for ages to get it to install under Hyper-V (Windows 10), and I've ruled out most other possible problems, other than the GRUB install/config.

Everything seems to go well when I install it, no errors or anything, but when I try to boot, it enters into a console mode, no matter how many times I reinstall. I've followed the tutorials to the letter and tried looking everywhere for answers, but I haven't found any.

Partitions:

- `/dev/sda1`: 512M vfat EFI System
- `/dev/sda2`: 8G Linux Swap
- `/dev/sda3`: 127G Linux x86-64 root

`/dev/sda3` was mounted to `/mnt`

`/dev/sda1` was mounted to `/mnt/boot` (i created the folder before mounting)

Then I ran `pacstrap /mnt base-devel`, `genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab` and `arch-chroot /mnt`.

After that, I installed the grub and efibootmgr packages and ran `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

The tutorials I've been following:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hyper-V

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB

screengrabs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GYTN.jpg

Comment: What vm generation do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've successfully installed GRUB.

However, there are no entries because you haven't created an initramfs in the `/boot` partition.

As per the [wiki's installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Initramfs):

> a new initramfs is usually not required, because `mkinitcpio` was run on installation of the `linux` package with `pacstrap`.

I noticed you didn't actually `pacstrap` the [`base` group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/base/) - in which the `linux` package is contained.

Run `$ pacstrap /mnt base` from the installation media. This will pull in the basic packages needed on an Arch system, including `linux`. Installing `linux` will also generate the initramfs automatically.

You'll then likely have to re-run `grub-mkconfig` so the entries can be created.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to move EFI to /boot/efi instead of /boot to avoid risks of masking /boot.